# Global Function to Return Parsed JSON?

Tags: json, swift, xcode

I'm trying to make this method accessible throughout the app because there are many view controllers need JSON response depending on the path and the language parameters, but I'm not sure what pattern to use or how to structure the app.

```
func fetchJsonFor(path: String, langugae: String) -> AnyObject{
        var components = URLComponents()
        components.scheme = Constants.APIScheme
        components.host = Constants.APIHost
        components.path = Constants.APIPath
        components.path.append(path)
        components.path.append(langugae)

        let request = URLRequest(url: components.url!)
        var parsedJSON: AnyObject!
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error != nil{
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
                return
            }
            guard let data = data else{
                return
            }
            do{
                parsedJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as AnyObject
            } catch{
                print("Can't parse JSON: \(data)")
                return
            }
        }
        task.resume()
        return parsedJSON
    }
```

Comment: if do this function inside class you can using singleton,
if not inside class can you call direct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for Single Tone Design pattern.

Also remember you can't return the URLRequest response as functions return. It is a asynchronous task which not works in main thread.  So return will not work.

You need to make use of closure ----> a completion block will more suitable.

```
class WebService {

   static let shared = WebService()

   func fetchJsonFor(path: String, langugae: String,completion:((Any?) -> Void)){
      var components = URLComponents()
      components.scheme = Constants.APIScheme
      components.host = Constants.APIHost
      components.path = Constants.APIPath
      components.path.append(path)
      components.path.append(langugae)

      let request = URLRequest(url: components.url!)
      var parsedJSON: AnyObject!
      let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if error != nil{
            print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Error")
            completion(nil)
        }
        guard let data = data else{
            completion(nil)
        }
        do{
            parsedJSON =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)
            completion(parsedJSON)
        } catch{
            print("Can't parse JSON: \(data)")
            completion(nil)
        }
    }
    task.resume()
   }
}
```

How to use..
From your ViewController Class you can call web service like

```
    WebService.shared.fetchJsonFor(path: "YOUR_PATH", langugae: "YOUR_LANGUAGE") { (response) in
        if let response = response{
            // Success response
        }else{
            //Failed response
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, the completion handler was the piece I missed.